# Process event files into Azure EventHub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am fairly new to Azure .

I have a requirement where Source will send the event data in flat files. File will contain header and trailer records and events as data records. Each file will be in 10MB size and can contains about 50000-60000 events.

I want to process this file using python/scala and send the data into Azure eventhub. Can someone suggest me is this the best solution and how can I achieve this please?

Comment: It sounds like you already have a solution in place. What's the question?

Comment: I just want to know is this the best solution also if you can suggest me any links where i can get sample scala code to build this that would be reat

Answer (score 0):

Its an architectural question but you can use either Azure Logic Apps or Azure Functions.

First of all you should trigger whatever you choose by upload a file to Blob Storage. The file will gets picked and processed and then sent.

Use Azure Logic apps if you can simply parse the files for instance because they are JSON files and then simply repeat for each event and direct it to the event hub you want.

If the parsing of the files is more complex use Azure Functions, write up the code and [output it to an event hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=csharp).